# Problems With or Alternative To Unidirectional has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two components to my application, for the most part, data entry/tracking and data reporting.

I have a basic data tracking object, let's call it Meter:

```
class Meter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activity_records
end
```

I have a collection of different reporting objects, like tabular reports, charts, widgets, etc. All of these objects, per user configuration, refer to a collection of Meters as data sources.

I model this relationship as `has_and_belongs_to_many`, through a join table: a Widget has many Meters; Meters can be referenced by many Widgets.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meters
end
```

Now, I don't think Meters actually need to know which reporting objects reference them. A Meter should be able to exist blithely, collecting data and (through a Service object) responding to data requests. I should never, ever, refer to `@meter.widgets`.

So, do I need, in the Meter model, to declare half a dozen different habtm relationships for all the different reporting objects?

**Concrete Questions:**
1. Are there unintended consequences from omitting the habtm declaration on Meters?
2. Is there a better way to design this relationship?

With regard to the second question, I have played with the concept of a `MeterSet` but found it a bit over-engineered:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :meter_set, as: :requester
  has_many :meters, through: :meter_set
end 

class MeterSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requester, polymorphic: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meters
end
```

I've moved the location of the join from one model to another... and I suppose I've reduced the number of tables in my application, overall?